# SpriteKit Actions.sks file need to preload?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit

I created an Actions.sks file for my game. I've noticed that the first time one of the actions from the file is executed my game glitch's a little bit.

Example: My player comes in contact with a specific block, and that is when it happens. It is a 2d platformer and the camera glitches a little bit. Every other time an action is executed it is fine, it is just that first time.

Do I need to pre-load this file and if so how would this be done?

If you think it could be a different issue, I would love to find out some thoughts.

Thanks!!!

Comment: It's just the matter of initializing the variable in question with an actual file name.

Comment: Well that was easy enough. So I just initialized one of the actions within the file. I guess that was enough to load the file and get it going. my code: _ = SKAction.init(named: "ExAction")

Comment: Is there a more eloquent way to initialize the file?

Comment: You can create a singleton to read all files (audio clips, images...) at a time when the application starts up.

Comment: I would need to research what a singleton was first, but I can see the value of loading everything needed when the app starts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear out the glitch I did what @El Tomato recommended. I initialized one of the actions in my Actions.sks file:

_ = SKAction.init(named: "ExAction")

Once I did this, all actions ran fine with out the glitch.